# push to another view controller without prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

How can you push to another view controller without `prepareForSegue`?

```
myClassVC *viewController = [myClassVC alloc];
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"pushToMyVC" source:self destination:viewController];

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMyVC"]) {
 NSLog(@"logging");
 myClassVC *viewController = (myClassVC *)[segue destinationViewController];
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];        
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to programmatically invoke a push segue, you give the segue a "storyboard id" in Interface Builder and then you can:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"pushToMyVC" sender:self];
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to perform the segue, you can instantiate the destination view controller and then manually push to that view controller. All you need to do is to make sure that the destination view controller has its own "storyboard id" in Interface Builder, then you can:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

You said "push" (and hence I used `pushViewController` above). If you really meant to "present a modal view controller", then that second line is:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

As you can see, you don't *have* to use `prepareForSegue` to push to new scene. You only use `prepareForSegue` if you want to pass information to the destination view controller. Otherwise it is not needed.

Clearly, if you're not using storyboards (e.g., you're using NIBs), then the process is entirely different. But I assume you're not using NIBs because `prepareForSegue` is not applicable in that environment. But if you were using NIB, it would be as follows:

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: This answer is very very useful!

Answer (score 3):

`[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];` is not needed, as the segue will push the destination view controller using the transition you selected automatically.

If you don't want to use the `segue` process you'll need to manually push the view controller with:

`[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

but make sure you remove the segues in the Storyboard first.

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerID"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case all viewControllers are built dynamically. I do not make use of the storyboard for this purpose. Should this be your case you may just instantiate the viewController class you want to open and make a push as in my example below:

```
MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How can I prepare for segue in this case?

Comment: Easy! You just do it after the viewController instantiation and before you invoke the pushViewController method. You can set some public properties of the viewController, for instance.