# Transferring to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I am currently loading another viewcontroller on this code

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

NewViewController *controller = [[NewController alloc]init];
controller.licensed =@"NO";
controller.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But the problem is when the NewViewController loads. The subviews of the previous view controller is in the background of the NewViewController

```
[self.rectHolder performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self.btnSignup performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I tried to use this, but the subviews is still in the background of the new view controller

Edit:

I also tried to use this

```
NewViewController* viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
viewController.licensed = @"NO";
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But the subViews of my previous viewcontroller is still in the background

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: I'm on Objective-C, so nope

Comment: @Supermannoying are you changing rootView? and are you writing this code in AppDelegate ?

Comment: @RahulMishra what do you mean by changing rootView? Is is this line self.window.rootViewController = controller;? Nope, I am note writing this in AppDelegate

Comment: @Supermannoying so why are you doing this. Why are you not using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]`

Comment: Ya you need to learn basics of ios app.

Comment: @Supermannoying You only want to push a new view controller from another view controller right ?

Comment: Yup, that's it basically @RahulMishra

Comment: @Supermannoying for pushing a view controller you need a Navigation Controller. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371995/push-to-another-view-controller-without-prepareforsegue

Comment: @RahulMishra please see my edit

Comment: @Supermannoying can you post screen shot here what you are getting. And I am not able to get why are you adding to window?